# PostgresQL Altering BigAutoField on large table

Tags: sql, django, database, postgresql

I am currently trying to alter a normal Autofield to a Bigautofield using PostgesQL (and Django as framework). The process is going on for one day now and it seems that this is going to take forever as my database reached 2.147.483.647 rows.

Is there any workaround to shift around this issue? Any hacks?

Thanks in advance

Comment: number of entries is really high for it to complete in 24 hrs, it needs to process approx 25k rows/sec.

Comment: What is the command which is getting run on the server, after Django is done doing whatever it does to it?